# validation on user input ruby

Tags: ruby, input, command-line-interface

I created a gem that looks for a recipe with user input. I have almost 1000 recipes available to search for. How can I validate the user input when it does not match the names of my recipes?

as an example when the user type nabucodonosor or vocka the method load_recipe_by_ingridients return empty and I wish I could fix that. I'm using Ruby vanilla.. no rails

```
def start
  puts "Hey there! you hungry? lets find some recipes ideas for you."
        
  list_recipe_by_ingredients
  show_summary
    
  while @input != "exit" 
    if @input == "back"
      list_recipe_by_ingredients
    elsif valid_input?
      puts Recipe.find_by_number(@input).summary
    else
      puts "Ops! not a valid number. try again."
    end

    ask_for_choices
  end
end

def load_recipe_by_ingredients
  puts "Search for recipes with the main ingredient, example: milk, pizza, eggs flour, ect."
  @input = gets.strip.downcase
  puts " "
  Recipe.search_for_recipes(@input).each.with_index(1) do |recipe, index|
    puts "#{index}. #{recipe.title}"
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you want it to do instead? What do you mean by validate? What would valid input look like? What would invalid input look like?

Comment: Hi, I am searching for recipes by user input but when that input does not exist in my recipes object I want to tell the user to try again. valid input will be bread, pizza, eggs, or anything related to food. when I put something that is not food-related my list method returns empty.

Comment: Well, how are you calling `load_recipe_by_ingredients`? Is there some kind of loop? Show that code, please.

Comment: The code is on the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty simple solution is to `loop` until a recipe is found, and once one or more recipes are found you `break` out of the loop and then render them:

```
def load_recipe_by_ingredients
  recipes = []

  loop do
    puts 'Search for recipes with the main ingredient, example: milk, pizza, eggs flour, etc.'
    input = gets.strip.downcase
    puts
    recipes = Recipe.search_for_recipes(input)
    break if recipes.any?
    puts 'No recipes found, please try again'
  end

  recipes.each.with_index(1) do |recipe, index|
    puts "#{index}. #{recipe.title}"
  end
end
```